Dipole and Ring electric field
Suppose a dipole is given along the axis of a charged ring which is at a position where electric field is maximum. Consider ring radius $R$ and dipole moment $\mathbf{p}$ along the axis and all other necessity constants as usual.
However, if you perform the calculations you'll get zero as answer.
Why is it? From theory, I can confirm that force on dipole is zero in constant $\mathbf{E}$. Am I thinking correctly?

Please can you clarify: what are you calculating? The Force on the dipole? Torque?

Your question is alternatively: Prove that net force on a dipole, placed along axis of a uniformly charged ring, is zero at points where the field is maximum.

What I think you ask: At what point(s) on the axis of a charged ring, if a dipole is kept, stays in equilibrium; and why?
Let me answer that.
First, let me clarify that keeping a dipole at a point implies coinciding the center of the dipole with that point.
If we keep the dipole at any point (other than where the field is max.) on the axis of the ring, the net force on it is not zero; and if we keep the dipole at the point where the field due to the ring is maximum gives no net force on it. Let me prove both by a graph.
The field due to a uniformly charged ring on its axis is given by: $E = \frac{KQx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$, where $x$ is the distance of the point from the center of the ring where field is $E$, $a$ is radius of the ring, and $Q$ is the total charge on the ring, distributed uniformly.
The graph must look like:

Notice that the $x-axis$ can be taken as the axis of the ring if the center of the ring is taken to be at the origin with plane of ring perpendicular to $x-axis$.
Let us keep the dipole (i.e. its center) at the point where field is maximum in the positive x-direction, say. Doing so symmetrically places the dipole about the $x = \frac{a}{\sqrt2}$ line, so for both the charges of the dipole the force applied is the same!, but in the opposite directions. So they cancel out; net force is zero.
Note that the graph is symmetric about the points of maxima/minima only for a small range, $\triangle x$. Obviously, the length of the dipole is very small compared to its separation from the ring, so such a technique is valid.
This will not happen for any other point, because there is no point, from which going right by $\triangle x$ and going left by $\triangle x$, we obtain the same value of field, except the points of maxima/minima, because graph is symmetric about them for small values of $\triangle x$.
You may do the same about $x = -\frac{a}{\sqrt2}$.
$x = \frac{a}{\sqrt2}$ is point of maxima, and $x = -\frac{a}{\sqrt2}$ is point of minima for the graph shown. However, the absolute values at both points are the same and maximum, hence physically, both are points where net force on dipole is zero.
The following image illustrates the above discussion:

You are right in saying that the force on a dipole is zero in constant external electric field. But that is not the only situation where such a thing happens, the charged ring is yet another example where at two of its axial points, net force on a dipole is equal to zero.

Consider a dipole containing $2$ point charges of magnitude $q$ with separation $2d$ between them placed along the axis of the given uniformly charged ring of radius $R$ and total charge $Q$. (Note that $d<<R$, i.e., in other words, it can be considered that $d\to0$.)
Let its centre be at a distance $x$ from the centre of the ring when the net force on the dipole is zero. Then,
$$\vec{F_{\text{net}}}=\vec0$$
$$\implies \frac{kQq(x+d)}{\left((x+d)^2+R^2\right)^\frac32}=\frac{kQq(x-d)}{\left((x-d)^2+R^2\right)^\frac32}$$
$$\implies \frac{x+d}{(x^2+R^2+2xd+d^2)^\frac32}=\frac{x-d}{(x^2+R^2-2xd+d^2)^\frac32}$$
As $d\to0$, $d^2\to0$ faster than $d$, so in the above computation, it can be ignored as it is added to $x^2+R^2\pm2xd$:
$$\implies \frac{x+d}{\left(x^2+R^2+2xd\right)^\frac32}=\frac{x-d}{\left(x^2+R^2-2xd\right)^\frac32}$$
Dividing throughout by $(x^2+R^2)^{-\frac32}$,
$$(x+d)\left(1+\frac{2xd}{x^2+R^2}\right)^{-\frac32}=(x-d)\left(1-\frac{2xd}{x^2+R^2}\right)^{-\frac32}$$
Using the binomial approximation $(1+x)^n\approx1+nx$ for $x<<1$,
$$(x+d)\left(1-\frac{3xd}{x^2+R^2}\right)=(x-d)\left(1+\frac{3xd}{x^2+R^2}\right)$$
$$\implies d=\frac{3x^2d}{x^2+R^2}$$
$$\implies \boxed{x=\pm\frac{R}{\sqrt2}}$$
Also, $x=\pm\frac{R}{\sqrt2}$ gives the points where the magnitude of the electric field due to the ring is maximum:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{kQx}{(x^2+R^2)^{\frac32}}\right)=0$$
$$\implies \frac{R^2-2x^2}{(x^2+R^2)^\frac52}=0$$
$$\implies x=\pm\frac{R}{\sqrt2}$$
The extrema are verified by the second derivative of the electric field at the concerned points:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\left(\frac{kQx}{(x^2+R^2)^{\frac32}}\right)\bigg{|}_{x=\frac{R}{\sqrt2}}=\frac{3kQx(2x^2-3R^2)}{(x^2+R^2)^\frac72}\bigg{|}_{x=\frac{R}{\sqrt2}}=\frac{-16kQ}{3^\frac52R^4}<0$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\left(\frac{kQx}{(x^2+R^2)^{\frac32}}\right)\bigg{|}_{x=-\frac{R}{\sqrt2}}=\frac{3kQx(2x^2-3R^2)}{(x^2+R^2)^\frac72}\bigg{|}_{x=-\frac{R}{\sqrt2}}=\frac{16kQ}{3^\frac52R^4}>0$$
But since $E(x)=\frac{kQx}{(x^2+R^2)^{\frac32}}$ is an odd function, the magnitudes of the electric fields at $x=\pm\frac{R}{\sqrt2}$ are the same.
